# How to make sure user has bought some device?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, authorization, iot

I am currently working on a project, where I have hardware device with some sensors etc., and web application, that can show the data to the user, and gives user some control over device.

One user can have many devices, so I need to make some sort of system, where user can add device to his account. And here is the part, where I have encountered an issue.

**How can I know, that user has bought (or basically just owns) a device, that can be used with application?**

My first thought was: Ok, just add some kind of key to each device, and tell the user to provide this, when they add device. But then I thought - how make sure that key is correct?

Should I make collections in my DB, where all proper keys are stored, check if key provided by user exists, remove key from DB and allow user to add device?

I am using:

- MongoDB
- Express.js
- Mongoose,

to create my API. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks for your time, and I wish you nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a table of devices in your database.
Then ask the user to add device id,
then check

```
if user deviceid exists in devices table
```

Comment: Should I use the same database as I use for my API?

Comment: Yes, You should use the same

Comment: Should I make some kind of Admin panel just for adding new products keys? Or maybe they should be generated automatically, and only admin has access to them (to get them and add to device)?

Comment: Giving the admin some right rights is always a nice option to go with. You can use an admin panel or You can add a field named as Role in your User Table in which only the admin will have role=admin otherwise all users will have Role = user, and while making any change in your program you can check if(Role==Admin) allow to make change

Comment: Thanks for you time, I think that it is the best option! I was also thinking about QR code, but I asked myself what if someone does not have webcam on the PC? Then he/she would be stucked :D